# Prove that 1 divides every integer, and that every integer divides 0

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I was asked to prove that $1$ divides every integer and that every integer divides $0$.

I wanted some help to see how others would answer this to improve my own answer. I also wanted to ask if anyone had suggestions to help me improve my solution.

Answer: $a = qb$.

The formula above determines if $a$ is divisible by $b$ for some integer $q$.

Prove that $1$ divides every integer: Since $1$ is a factor of every integer, $1$ divides every integer. a = q \cdot 1$. So $a = q$

Since $q$=$a$, for any integer $q$, $a$ can be any integer.

Since $a$ can be any integer, by $((a / 1) = q)$, $1$ can divide any integer.

Prove every integer divides $0$. $a = qb$. $(0 / b) = q (Assuming “b” is not equal to 0)$. $0 = q$.

Since $q$ is equal to $0$ for any integer $q$, $q$ has to be equal $0$ for any integer of $b$ that is not $0$.

Since $q$ is equal to $0$ for any integer $q$ except $0$, every integer except $0$, can divide $0$.

Comment: Avoid using *division* when talking about *divisibility*.  These are related concepts, to be sure, but you will not have formally defined division until several units (*or even classes*) after being introduced to divisibility.  The correct proof should have been that by letting $q=0$ we have $0=0\cdot b$ is in fact true so there does in fact exist an integer $q$ such that $0=qb$ regardless the value of $b$.  No division needed.

Comment: @JMoravitz. Thanks for the feedback. I'm slightly confused though. How do we know we have to set q = 0 initially as a proof?

Comment: @CodingKook We don't _have to_ set $q=0$; that's answering a different question.  We _can_ set $q=0$, which is all that matters.  More detailed: note you are not proving "the only quotient when $0$ is divided by a nonzero integer is $0$" which is a question of _uniqueness_ of $q$ and _would_ require you to show $q=0$.  You are proving "every integer divides zero" which asks us whether there is a $q$ such that $0=qb$.  With the question of _existence_, we can answer by simply choosing $q=0$, and this works for any integer $b$, even $0$.